# Uploading files to AWS with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm currently trying to upload images to AWS but keep getting `Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError: unable to sign request without credentials set`.
In my current setup I configure paperclip defaults setting as the following in my `application.rb` file.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV["s3_bucket"],
    :access_key_id => ENV["s3_access_key_id"],
    :s3_secret_access_key => ENV["s3_secret_access_key"],
    :s3_region => ENV["s3_region"]
  }
}
```

Then in my `application.yml` I set the values of the variables like so

```
development:
   s3_bucket: "open-doors-dev"

production:
  s3_bucket: "open-doors-pro"

s3_region: "us-west-1"
s3_access_key_id: "MY ACCESS KEY HERE"
s3_secret_access_key: "MY SECRET KEY HERE"
```

However when I try and test this code in the rails console I get the above error. I printed out the values of `config.paperclip_defaults` in my code and they match the values that I supplied in `application.yml` so I do not understand why this code is failing.

Comment: When testing in the rails console, are all the ENV variables set?

Comment: Yes they are @akz92

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going wrong. I had two problem the first being that in paper_clip defaults; `:s3_secret_access_key` should have just been `secret_access_key` the second being I had to change my policy to an inline policy though I'm unsure as to why that was giving me an error.